# How do you edit extensions_additonial.conf in asterisk?

Tags: asterisk, freepbx

I need to change one character in the file, but Asterisk overwrites that file. How can I make the changes persistent?

Answer (score 2):

That file is automatically created by FreePBX on every reload, as stated in the header:

```
;--------------------------------------------------------------------------------;
; Do NOT edit this file as it is auto-generated by FreePBX. All modifications to ;
; this file must be done via the web gui. There are alternative files to make    ;
; custom modifications, details at: http://freepbx.org/configuration_files       ;
;--------------------------------------------------------------------------------;
;
```

To override an existing dialplan, you need to put your code into `/etc/asterisk/extensions_override_freepbx.conf`. Despite that you only want to change one character, you will need to copy the entire context into this file.

To create new dialplan, as mentioned in the answer from MichelV69, you would indeed use `/etc/asterisk/extensions_custom.conf`. This will not work for modifying existing dialplan, due to order in which files are included.

Comment: Remember to also copy the section name at the top... (i.e. `[ext-meetme]` one line before the `exten => 123,1,...`)

Answer (score 0):

You don't.  Per the documentation, you reproduce the section you want to override in extensions_custom.conf and make your changes there.

Also, this is for "FreePBX", not "Asterisk".  Asterisk natively doesn't use / come-with "extensions_additional.conf".